# How to get the value of an attribute from an array using Path Expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider the below sample xml.

```
<Groups>
    <Group id="01" check="true">
        <name>Value</name>
        <age>test</age>
        <setData>
            <data type="module">module</data>
            <data enabled="true">true</data>
        </setData>
    </Group>
    <Group id="02" check="true">
        <name>Value</name>
        <age>test</age>
        <setData>
            <data type="module">module</data>
            <data enabled="true">true</data>
        </setData>
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

I want to get the value for enabled in setData for GroupId = 1 using Path Expression.
Below is my try. It is a temporary fix for the problem, but looks for the position in array.

```
String groupId = "1"; //to make group id dynamic.
String pathExpression = "Groups/group[@id='"+groupId+"']/setData/data[2]/text()"
```

Instead of this, I want to get the value by giving the attribute name "enabled", so that it will check for the name instead of position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using the correct syntax for getting `group` by an attribute value, so just do something similar for the `data` element too, except you don't need to check the attribute value, just that it exists.....

```
String pathExpression = "Groups/group[@id='"+groupId+"']/setData/data[@enabled]/text()"
```

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the advise.